# If statement colon invalid syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to run the program but it comes up with a invalid syntax error and highlights the colon

```
if operation==+ :
    print("Your answer is ", number1+number2)
```

Comment: You want to wrap that `+` in quotes I think -> `"+"`

Comment: Can you show how you obtain the variable `operation`? Depending on what it is you should use `"+"` or `operator.add`

Comment: Unclear what `operation` is supposed to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that there is no type to represent the value `+`. You probably had a string representing the `+`, i.e. `"+"`. To do the correct comparison, you should replace your former code with:

```
if operation == "+" :
    print("Your answer is ", number1+number2)
```

If `operation` is not a string, but an `operator` from the imported module, you should use:

```
if operation == operator.add:
    print("Your answer is ", number1+number2)
```

Comment: I *really* doubt it's `operator.add` but props for thinking about it.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard I have doubts too :))

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if operation==+
```

with

```
if operation == '+':
```

as `+` itself is not a value of any type.